# JMS temporary queue discards first message

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I'm sending JMS requests to a Weblogic 10.3 server through a named JMS queue, and receive a reply back through a temporary queue.

Client (barebone):

```
//init
Destination replyQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
replyConsumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue);
...
//loop
TextMessage requestMessage = session.createTextMessage();
requestMessage.setText("Some request")
requestMessage.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
requestProducer.send(requestMessage);
Message msg = replyConsumer.receive(5000);
if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
    ...
} else { ... }
//loop end
```

Server MDB (message driven bean):

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
        ...
        TextMessage replyMessage = jmsSession.createTextMessage();
        replyMessage.setText("Some response");
        replyMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(msg.getJMSCorrelationID());
        replyProducer.send(replyMessage);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the very first server reply is often lost! That is, the `replyConsumer.receive(5000)` ends with timeout for every 4th-5th replyConsumer. When the consumer receives the first answer, then it continues to receive all the rest, so the problem is only with the first message send through the temporary queue after the temp queue has been created.

**My question:** Do I have to set something special for the temporary queue in order it works from the very start after being created? Or any other hint?

Further info:

- When testing against my local development machine, the temp queues work without problem. The messages are getting lost only when testing against our clustered Weblogic server. However, I have switched off all cluster members but one instance.
- I have verified that the server *successfully* replies all the requests that the client sends (by counting the sent requests and sent replies). The server replies in the order of milliseconds, even for the lost replies.
- When I replace the temporary queue with a regular named queue, the problem disappears! So the problem doesn't seem (to me) to be in my code.
- I've also tried to modify expiration, persistency, delay etc. of the reply message, but without success. This way I excluded the scenario that the response arrives earlier than the client begins to read the queue, and then the message immediately expires not giving the client a chance to process it.
- **Edit:** Instead of the synchronous `replyConsumer.receive(5000)` I've also tried to use the asynchronous `replyConsumer.setMessageListener(this)`. The behaviour hasn't changed, first messages are still getting lost for temp queues.

**Edit:** It seems that there's something wrong with the Weblogic server (or cluster) I am using. Because when I deployed the server application to another Weblogic cluster we have, everything began to work correctly! Both clusters should be configured identically - so where's a difference? It scares me that the Weblogic signals no error.

Comment: We haven't found the reason for this bad behaviour. However, re-creation of the domain has helped - the new domain works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that sometimes the server is receiving the publish and discarding it before your consumer has started receiving.

The way around it is to use the asynchronous receive (replyConsumer.setMessageListener) calls instead of the blocking call you currently have (replyConsumer.receive(5000)) and to add the call to the code with the rest of your consumer code.

That way, you are already listening for replies before you send out the request.

Hope that helps.

Edit: Just read that you are using a temporary queue, so my first sentence is not correct. However as an experiment try the rest of my response to see if it changes the behaviour you are seeing

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but without success. I edited my post and added further info.